# Github sort PRs by largest number of files changed

Tags: github

In Github, is it possible to sort Pull Requests by largest (or smallest) number of files changed?
I'm trying to get some stats on the large / small PRs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using [GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql) you can efficiently ask for a [repository's](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/reference/objects#repository) list of [Pull Requests](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/reference/objects#pullrequest), how many files they changed, and any other fields you're interested in. Then you can sort that array by changedFiles.

```
query { 
    repository(owner:"octocat", name:"linguist") {
    pullRequests(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        number
        changedFiles
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in...

```
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "pullRequests": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "number": 1,
            "changedFiles": 1
          },
          {
            "number": 2,
            "changedFiles": 2028
          },
          {
            "number": 3,
            "changedFiles": 2
          },
          {
            "number": 4,
            "changedFiles": 1
          },
          {
            "number": 5,
            "changedFiles": 267
          },
          {
            "number": 9,
            "changedFiles": 2
          },
          {
            "number": 11,
            "changedFiles": 886
          },
          {
            "number": 12,
            "changedFiles": 2
          },
          {
            "number": 13,
            "changedFiles": 1
          },
          {
            "number": 14,
            "changedFiles": 1483
          },
          {
            "number": 17,
            "changedFiles": 1
          },
          {
            "number": 22,
            "changedFiles": 2
          },
          {
            "number": 23,
            "changedFiles": 1
          },
          {
            "number": 24,
            "changedFiles": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```